# How can I sort all worksheets in my Google spreadsheet on open?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, sorting

I have successfully been able to sort the first sheet in my Google Spreadsheet `onOpen`, but I'd like to sort all four spreadsheets `onOpen` and I can't make this work. I've tried quite a few variations in Script Editor; here's my latest:

```
function onOpen(){
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Sorts the first sheet by the first column, ascending
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var tableRange = sheet.getRange("A3:L999"); // What to sort.
  tableRange.sort({column: 1, ascending: true});

  // Sorts the second sheet by the first column, ascending
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheets()[1];
  var tableRange1 = sheet1.getDataRange("A3:AC999"); // What to sort.
  tableRange1.sort({column: 1, ascending: true});

  // Sorts the third sheet by the first column, ascending
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheets()[2];
  var tableRange2 = sheet2.getDataRange("A3:N999"); // What to sort.
  tableRange2.sort({column: 1, ascending: true});

  // Sorts the fourth sheet by the first column, ascending
  var sheet3 = ss.getSheets()[3];
  var tableRange3 = sheet3.getDataRange("A3:AC999"); // What to sort.
  tableRange3.sort({column: 1, ascending: true});
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this instead.

### Code

```
function onOpen() {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();  
  for(var i = 0, iLen = sheets.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    var sheet = sheets[i], range = sheet.getDataRange();
    range.sort({column: 1, ascending: true});
  }
}
```

If you want to sort from a certain row or column, then use this code

```
function onOpen() {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for(var i = 0, iLen = sheets.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    var sheet = sheets[i], lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();    
    var range = sheet.getRange(3,1,lastRow, lastColumn);
    range.sort({column: 1, ascending: true});
  }
}
```

or this

```
function onOpen() {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var dataRange = ["A3:L999","A3:AC999", "A3:N999", "A3:AC999"];
  for(var i = 0, iLen = sheets.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    var sheet = sheets[i], range = sheet.getRange(dataRange[i]);
    range.sort({column: 1, ascending: true});
  }
}
```