# Sort sheet tabs name alphabetically

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

This is a script I located to sort my sheet tab names alphabetically. Is it safe for me to use in my free version of Google Sheets?

```
function sortSheets () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetNameArray = [];
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
   
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    sheetNameArray.push(sheets[i].getName());
  }
  
  sheetNameArray.sort();
    
  for( var j = 0; j < sheets.length; j++ ) {
    ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameArray[j]));
    ss.moveActiveSheet(j + 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. What do you mean by "safe for me"?

Comment: Possible related: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/70200/88163

Comment: The code seems fine for sorting sheet names into JavaScript lexicographical order and re-ordering the sheets in the tab bar that way. Whether it is "safe for you" depends on what you actually need and on whether the sheet names are such that it makes sense to sort them lexicographically.

Answer (score 1):

This code works "as advertised". I've just tested it and it does sort your sheets alphabetically. No more, no less. If you're unsure, you can do what I did: create a dummy spreadsheet with a couple of sheets, move the sheets out of order, then run the script.

**PERMISSIONS**

If you have a script that makes changes to the spreadsheet, then before it is executed for the first time, you (the user) need to give it permission to run, and to access your spreadsheet (or whatever services the script accesses). This is probably the point at which you "received a message from google sheets not to trust this code".

The following are the popups that you should see when you click `Run` for the first time.

**1 - Authorization Required**

[image: authorisation required]

- Self-explanatory
- Click "Review Permissions" to continue

---

**2 - Choose an account**

[image: chooseanaccount]

- Your login account is listed, but you can choose another account if you wish.
- Click the account that you want to use.

---

**3 - Google hasn't verified this app - #1**

[image: Googlehasntverified]

- This is Google's way of saying, "this has nothing to do with us - you wrote it so it's all up to you".

  - The part in red will be your email address.
- Click "**Advanced**" to continue

---

**4 - Google hasn't verified this app - #2**

[image: googleagain]

- Again, the bits in red should be your email account.
- At the bottom of this popup, you'll see a link saying something like "Go to 'project name' (unsafe)". The 'project name' contains your script.
- Click this link to continue

The word "**unsafe**" here simply means that Google hasn't verified it; the onus is on you to satisfy yourself that the script is OK and won't destroy your work/files/etc.

---

**5- The project wants to access your work**

[image: wants access]

- In this case the script can "see, edit, create and delete **all** my spreadsheets".
- Depending on the specific code, it might also/instead want access to Google Drive, &/or Gmail, &/or Calendar and so on.
- This is the point where you accept (or not) responsibility and allow the script to "Run".

  - If you OK with this, click "**Allow**"